# GitHub Actions: Conditional parameter value for custom action

Tags: conditional-statements, github-actions

I have a custom action that takes multiple inputs.
I want to pass one value in one case and another in any other case.
I prefer to avoid putting a condition over the whole action and duplicate it.
Is there any way to achieve this? Something in the are of:

```
    - name: Custom action
      uses: ./.github/actions/custom/
      with:
        param: "value"
        ${{ if [condition]}}
        param2: "value1"
        ${{ else }}
        param2: "value2"
```

(I know there is no "else", this is just to illustrate what I am looking for)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "[steps.if](https://You%20can%20use%20the%20if%20conditional%20to%20prevent%20a%20step%20from%20running%20unless%20a%20condition%20is%20met.%20You%20can%20use%20any%20supported%20context%20and%20expression%20to%20create%20a%20conditional.%20For%20more%20information%20on%20which%20contexts%20are%20supported%20in%20this%20key,%20see)", as the docs suggest:

> You can use the if conditional to prevent a step from running unless a condition is met. You can use any supported context and expression to create a conditional.

The workflow would then look something like this:

```
    - name: Custom action on condition 1
      if: ${{ condition_1 }}
      uses: ./.github/actions/custom/
      with:
        param: "value"
        param2: "value1"
    - name: Custom action on condition 2
      if: ${{ condition_2 }}
      uses: ./.github/actions/custom/
      with:
        param: "value"
        param2: "value2"
```

Your `condition_2` would be the "else" case in this setup.

Comment: This is something I prefer to avoid, too much duplication. I was hoping for something a but more elegant